# Найти сумму модулей элементов массива, которые идут после элемента со значением 0

Tags: c++, c++builder

Дошел до такого кода:

```
 int i, s = 0, a[10], el = -1;      
 a[0] = 3;
 a[1] = -1;
 a[2] = 2;
 a[3] = 0;
 n = 4;

for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        if(a[i]==0){
        el = i;
        }
        break;
        }
for (i = el; i<n; i++){
     s+=fabs(a[i]);
     }
Label3->Show();
if (el == -1){
Label3->Caption ="В массиве 0 нет";
}
else if (el == (n-1)){
Label3 -> Caption = "0 является последним элементом";
}

else {
Label3->Caption = "Сумма равна "+IntToStr(s);
}
```

Однако при запуске с этими числами вместо задуманного "0 является последним элементом" выводит "В массиве 0 нет". Где ошибка, а то не нахожу

Comment: А чему n равно? У вас не указано..

Comment: Voidificator, извиняюсь, не скопировал. 4

Comment: `break;` -> `if () { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
  if(a[i] == 0) {
    el = i;
    break; // должен быть тут
  }
  // а не тут
}
```

Comment: финиш по секундомеру?

Comment: 15:52:50 у обоих, а SO в БД хранит с точностью до секунды, так что ничья :D

Comment: Сломаю равенство голосов. С комментариями ответ лучше, чем без ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] == 0) {
    el = i;
    break;
  }
}
```